# Can a barbarian dual wield with Giant Instinct?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, barbarian, two-weapon-fighting, oversized-weapons

The ability Giant instinct gives you access to an oversized weapon:

> You gain access to this larger weapon, which can be of any weapon type otherwise available at character creation. **It** has the normal Price and Bulk for a weapon of its size. When wielding such a weapon in combat, increase your additional damage from Rage from 2 to 6, but you have the clumsy 1 condition because of the weapon's unwieldy size.

I always thought this meant one piece of weaponry, but English is not my first language. I just saw a YouTube video suggesting that a Flurry Ranger could wield two such weapons, for Twin Takedown.

Can you have 2 oversized weapons, both dealing 6 extra damage if you have the Giant instinct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Only one of your two weapons must be larger

> **When wielding such a weapon in combat**, increase your additional damage from Rage from 2 to 6, but you have the clumsy 1 condition because of the weapon's unwieldy size.

The increased rage damage and clumsy condition require that you wield a larger weapon, but don't require you to strike with that larger weapon.

When you are wielding two swords in combat, one larger and the other normal, you meet the condition of the instict ability, so your rage damage increases and you are clumsy, even as you strike and deal damage with the normal sword.

Comment: Very elegant, I like it.

Answer (score 11):

### You can probably use two such weapons

I've come to the same conclusion as SpearCarrier.no2, but for a very different reason; I would interpret the rules even more loosely than them.

Giant Instinct seems to have been written assuming you would *only want* to use one oversized weapon. Certainly the first image it brings to mind is a Conan-sized Barbarian wielding a Cloud Strife-sized sword. However, I don't think it was intended to limit you to just one such weapon.

- As noted in another answer, it does not reference needing to replace the weapon(s) if lost
- It references gaining "access" to a weapon, implying that it is something that already existed and will continue to exist... but might be harder to locate for most people
- It references 'such a weapon', further showing that it does not necessarily have to be "one special weapon" like Amiri's
- The Specialization notes "Increase the damage from Rage **when using a larger weapon**"
- It does not say that oversized weapon(s) must be two-handed, nor wielded two-handed

For these reasons, I think you should be able to wield *any* weapon one size larger than you as a Giant Instinct Barbarian. You may be limited (unless gaining other access) when attempting to *find* such weapons other than the one you select at character creation, but there is nothing limiting you from using them once found, including using two at the same time.

This is consistent with the balancing principles on wielding two weapons as well; a Giant Instinct Barbarian is going to have limited access to the most powerful options relating to using two weapons and will otherwise have to spend Feats on Dual Weapon Warrior, Ranger Archetype, or Fighter Archetype and furthermore will get those Feats at a higher level than other characters.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, you can have two oversized weapons

(English is not my first language either, but I think this is not a linguistic question)

The instinct doesn't talk about "replacing" the way Mind Smith Dedication (or Pilgrim's Token) does, but "access", like with uncommon weapons.
Which makes me think it is "a weapon" like the Gnome Flickmace is; not an individual item, but a type.

So you can have 2 large Longswords, but not a large Longsword and a Shortsword.

Answer (score 1):

### It means a single weapon, but check with your GM

A weapon in normal English usage can be interpreted more widely, here are some dictionary definitions:

> - a thing designed or used for inflicting bodily harm or physical damage
> - a means of gaining an advantage or defending oneself in a conflict or contest

In the second sense, a weapon might well be a whole collection of arms, or even something entirely different, like treachery or intelligence.

But I think it is pretty clear the rules here refer to a single, physical weapon from the weapon tables that you gain access to. It consistently uses the singular and refers to its attributes such as bulk and size.

When the [weapon rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=218) talk about such attributes, they always refer to an individual instance, not a collection of weapons, and the [weapons table](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx) also lists individual weapons, even for those that might be commonly used as a pair.

This does not preclude that later in the game, you might find another oversized weapon, of someone to buy it from. The ability states you can use *such a weapon*, not *this weapon*. If you do obtain a second one, you would be able to use both. But initally, from the class feature, you would get only one.

All that said, if your character has a two-handed fighting style, and your GM has no concerns about the extra damage being unbalanced, it seems not to be a large stretch for you to be able to get two such larger weapons to fight with from the start.

Comment: How would you reconcile this with the access rules? Do you suppose that "gaining access" means that you may only ever use a single instance of that weapon? That's not my understanding of other feats that grant access, such as elf/dwarf/gnome weapon proficiency.